# how to give home button and app switcher button functionality to a custom button?

Tags: android

I am trying to make an onscreen touch navigation button application and currently unable to find a way to get my custom button function like android OS home and app switcher button.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if you have root or can use `android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system"` or not, so I am assuming you can't. In that case you can extend [AccessibilityService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService.html) and follow the guidelines [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/services.html).
After you setup your new service you can call [performGlobalAction](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService.html#performGlobalAction%28int%29) on it. In your case:

```
performGlobalAction(GLOBAL_ACTION_HOME);
```

and

```
performGlobalAction(GLOBAL_ACTION_RECENTS);
```

PS: Don't forget to go to system settings -> accessibility and enable your app.